# How to launch an activity in an Android App?

Tags: android-activity

I know how to use the intent to launch an activity is one method. 
I want to know whether there are any other methods.

What is the difference between them......

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Can you tell us why you want an alternative way to lauch an activity? Are there any limitations/problems with the intend mechanism that you want to solve?

Comment: No,there is no limitation or problem with intent mechanism. I am a freshman of android develop. I just want to know various mechanisms in android, and to understand android better.